# How to read SSD from 2015 MBP on new M2 mac

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, apple-silicon

My Mid2015 mbp suddenly stopped booting, so I got a new M2 mbp.  I have taken the SSD out of the old mac (it was an aftermarket one I had installed anyway) and put it into an external drive enclosure.

My new M2 mac will not recognize the drive though.  I've currently only got the ability to connect it via a

```
m2 mac <====> USB-C <====> USB-A hub <====> external drive
```

The drive lights up like it's connected, but macos shows nothing in finder.

Any ideas?

updates: I can see it in the terminal, but it does not show in /Volumes or `diskutil list`

```
jemminger@MacBook-Pro ~ % ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 36>
  +-o AppleT8112USBXHCI@00000000  <class AppleT8112USBXHCI, id 0x10000042a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (8 ms), retain 37>
  +-o AppleT8112USBXHCI@02000000  <class AppleT8112USBXHCI, id 0x10000041e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (66491 ms), retain 59>
  +-o AppleT8112USBXHCI@01000000  <class AppleT8112USBXHCI, id 0x100000465, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (53830 ms), retain 86>
    +-o USB2.1 Hub@01100000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000fe4, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (22 ms), retain 33>
    +-o USB3.1 Hub@01200000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x100000fe6, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (53811 ms), retain 33>
      +-o Envoy  @01230000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x10000100b, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (53787 ms), retain 27>
```

Comment: What exactly is the aftermarket drive? Did it use an adaptor to connect inside? What is the enclosure model?

Comment: @benwiggy it's an OWC aura 1tb ssd, I replaced the OEM ssd in the machine with it a few years ago.  The enclosure is the one OWC sent in the upgrade kit, it's an OWC "Envoy" enclosure

Comment: When you connect the drive, is it displayed in System Information?

Comment: @MarcWilson no, and all 3 thunderbolt devices still say "No device connected"... maybe I'll have to look for a direct to thunderbolt enclosure

Comment: Unless the hub you are using is a Thunderbolt device, it will not show up on the Thunderbolt report but will show up on the USB report.   Look there.

Comment: yep, does show up as a usb 3.1 device, updated the description with it

Comment: I would be tempted to say that you may want to try connecting it **directly** to the new MacBook. The multiple adapters/hub could possibly be the problem. Try an enclosure with direct USB-C on it. Also it seems possible that a non-bootable Mac (does it turn on and display anything?) might be blamed on a defective drive, like the one you are trying to read on your *new* Mac.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have a backup drive that you could migrate from, instead?

Comment: @benwiggy I do, I've gotten most everything back from that